# how to write 'not equal' in python for two answers?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I need to make a 'while' loop in my programme but cannot finish it off correctly. Below is what i have so far:

```
restart ="y"
while restart == "y":
    sentence = input("What is your sentence?: ")
    sentence_split = sentence.split() 
    sentence2 = [0]
    print(sentence)
    for count, i in enumerate(sentence_split): 
        if sentence_split.count(i) < 2:
            sentence2.append(max(sentence2) + 1)
        else:
            sentence2.append(sentence_split.index(i) +1)
    sentence2.remove(0)
    print(sentence2)
    outfile = open("testfile.py", "wt")
    outfile.write(sentence)
    outfile.close()
    print (outfile)
    restart = input("would you like restart the programme y/n?")
    if restart == "n":
        print ("programme terminated")
    else:
        print("you were asked y or n")
```

When "n" is entered then the loop works fine and it prints "programme terminated" but when "y" is entered it will restart the programme but also still print "you were asked y or n".

Answer (score 2):

That is because the program will follow the `else` if `restart` holds anything different than 'n'. (y or any other value). If you press 'y', it will then follow the `else` statement, and then the condition for the while will also evaluate to `true`. You can use a `elif restart != 'y'` as a quick solution, where the print statement is issued. Then you can set `restart` to `y` so that the loop repeats, or use a different variable for the loop altogether.

Answer (score 0):

use `while: true` and `break` to control `y/n` question, and remember to use `lower()` to get the lower case character only.

```
restart = 'y'
while (True):
    # other code goes here
    restart = raw_input("would you like restart the programme y/n?").lower()
    if (restart == 'n'):
        print ("programme terminated")
        break
    elif (restart == 'y'):
        pass
    else:
        print "Please enter y or n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way your if/else statement is structured. When you enter `y`, `n` fails in your if statement. Which means that your `else` statement is immediately executed. But after your else statement is executed, control flow loops to the next iteration off your while loop, and your program still restarts.

What you most likely want is to add a `break` statement under your else statement, so that flow of control does not loop to the next iteration of your while loop but exits it:

```
else:
    print("you were asked y or n")
    break # <---------- add a break statement under your else
```